# Why can't I find System.ServiceModel.WebHttpBinding?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have added references to the "System.ServiceModel" library, but the "WebHttpBinding" class is not in it.  According to the documentation, it should be there ([WebHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.aspx)).  I have tried this with both the 3.5 and 4.0 frameworks.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you referenced System.ServiceModel.Web.dll? i.e adding a reference to this specific dll?

Comment: That was the probelm.  I just referenced the System.ServiceModel.dll.  Post your answer as an actual answer, and I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add reference to System.ServiceModel.Web (System.ServiceModel.Web.dll).

Check in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.aspx).